# SQL Server index optimisation

Tags: sql-server

I've got this simple query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM emailmessages 
WHERE emaildate > @created 
  AND toaddresses like '%my@email.com%' 
  AND toaddresses is not null 
  AND toaddresses <> '' 
  AND fromaddress NOT LIKE '%my@email.com%' 
ORDER BY 
    emaildate DESC
```

The table is pretty big, and it was taking around 4 seconds to run. I added an index on toaddresses,fromaddress,emaildate which got it down to around 1.5 seconds. I know this isn't a lot but we have a script which runs this query around 100 times, so it mounts up.

Is there anything else I can do to optimise this? I'm having to use LIKE because the `toaddresses` look like this:

```
< s.***@l******s.co.uk >
```

`fromaddress` like this:

```
"R** F******" < r.f******@l*****s.co.uk >
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show us the execution plan for this query? Also how is your `emailmessages` table designed?

Comment: I\`m not sure sql server optimizer spots this,but your second LIKE can be replaced with `AND fromaddress <> toaddresses`

Comment: @BenDurkin another thing to consider is that the `toaddresses` cannot be an empty string (not talking about `null`) and satisfy the `LIKE` condition so the `<> ''` can be taken out.

Comment: A regular index will not help with `like` queries that start with a wildcard. Have a look at full-text search.

Comment: I would use Full text search - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: Whats the purpose of running this query so often?

Comment: Full text took it down to 32ms! Thanks for the advice.

Comment: You should consider converting the query to return the entire 100 records at once instead of runing a 100 times to return a single row. 32ms * 100 is still 3.2 seconds, a well indexed table with a well built query that returns the hole 100 rows should be able to return with a much better time.